# Accessing an Array list inside of another Array List through multiple classes

Tags: java

I am doing some practice with Java and had an example in my textbook that continues to stump me. The problem reads:

"P8.7 Modify the grade book application of How To 7.1 so that it can deal with multiple
students. First, ask the user for all student names. Then read in the scores for all
quizzes, prompting for the score of each student. Finally, print the names of all students
and their final scores. Use a single class and only static methods.
P8.8 Repeat Exercise P8.7, using multiple classes. Modify the GradeBook class so that it
collects objects of type Student. Each such object should have a list of scores."

I am currently on the 8.8 exercise. I understand how to use multiple classes and have a general understanding of how this problem should be solved. Earlier I created a program that acted as a "bank". This bank contained multiple "accounts" which were contained as separate objects of the "BankAccount" class. Each account had a separate balance and account number. I was able to create a method in the "bank" class to search by account number.. This did not get the balance however only told whether the account existed.

In my current problem I have a GradeBook class that will contain numerous objects of the "Student" class. Each of these "Students" will contain a list of grades kept as an ArrayList. The problem that I'm having is knowing exactly how to call an individual array list for a student so that it can be displayed. I've tried numerous methods but can't seem to wrap my mind around doing it. Could someone look at my code and tell me how I would retrieve the list of individual grades for a student in the final tester class? My tester class is not complete because I am stuck at this step but I believe you can get the picture..

GradeBookTester class

```
package gradebook_multi_class;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import bankAccount.Bank;

public class GradebookTester 

{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int counterMain=0;
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        GradeBook book = new GradeBook();

        System.out.println("Welcome to the gradebook utility!");

        do{

            System.out.println("Please enter a student name: ");
            String name = in.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter the student quiz grade: ");
            String grade = in.next();
            list.add(grade);
            list.add("3");

            book.addStudent(new Student(name,list));
            System.out.println("Do you have more students to add? (Y/N)");
            String input = in.next();
            if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){

            }else{
                counterMain=1;
            }



        }while(counterMain==0);



    }

}
```

GradeBook Class

```
package gradebook_multi_class;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GradeBook 

{

    private ArrayList<Student> students;

    public GradeBook(){

        students = new ArrayList<Student>();

    }

    public void addStudent(Student a){


        students.add(a);
    }

    public Student find(String aName){


        for(Student a: students){

            if(a.getName().equals(aName))

                return a;

        }

        return null;
    }


}
```

Student Class

```
package gradebook_multi_class;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Student 

{

    private String studentName;
    private ArrayList<String> grades = new ArrayList<String>();


    public Student(String aName, ArrayList<String> list){

        studentName = aName;
        grades=list;


    }

    public String getName(){

        return studentName;

    }


    public ArrayList<String> getGrades(){

        return grades;

    }

}
```

Comment: Well you already have the method `getGrades()` in the `Student` class to so I don't understand what your issue is :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already done all of the work, in your find method of the GradeBook class.

You'd just do, in your main class:

```
Student desiredStudent = book.find("Joe");
desiredStudent.getGrades();
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that worked perfectly! I knew I was close I just wasn't sure how to put it all together.

Answer (score 0):

> Finally, print the names of all students and their final scores.

If that is the problem then just like `Student.getGrades()` add a method `GradeBook.getStudents()`,

```
public ArrayList<Student> getStudents() {    
    return students.AsReadOnly();    
}
```

Then in the `main()` method,

```
for (Student student : students) {
    System.out.println("Student: " + student.getName());
    System.out.print("Grades: ");
    for (String grade : student.getGrades())
        System.out.println(grade + " ");
}
```